# Complete interaction through a form using C#

Tags: c#, click, transparent, interaction

I am making an overlay program with C# that will have an overlay for games. I am currently using a borderless form with a transparent background and a picture box to draw pictures to the screen, but I can't click the window behind the form. I have set the form to be always on top so that I can play games and the UI stays, but every time the mouse goes over the form in the game if I click the focused window switches to my form, preventing game interaction.

I have tried using functions to just draw images to the screen without using forms, but I cannot work out how to do that.

All I want is things like an external menu/crosshair and such, for use in minecraft. As for the menu, I could make my own media controls and such, and the crosshair would be useful because I hate the default crosshair. I could draw shapes to the screen, but if I don't use pictures the crosshair might look tacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is a **per pixel alpha blending window**.

Here is a good starting point: [Per Pixel Alpha Blend in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1822/Per-Pixel-Alpha-Blend-in-C)

The example source code should give you the idea.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure really what to do with that, would you mind quoting some code for me please?

Comment: You downloaded the sample application with code?: [Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp/PerPixelAlphaForm-101.zip)

Comment: Yes, but it does not allow you to click through the window. Is there any chance you can give me some specific code from that to activate the layer myself that I can put straight in my project and tweak please? Sorry, I don't mean to come off as lazy, but I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to this.

Comment: Ahha, I got it going! Thanks a lot man, Merry Christmas (or whatever you celebrate)!

Comment: Thank you. And a merry christmast too! A nice present would be to mark my answer as the solution ;)